# AngularJS Two Way Bind Property in Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive:

```
.directive('test', function () {

    return {
        scope: {},

        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            scope.$parent.$watch(attr.selectedItem, function(newValue, oldValue){
                scope.selectedItem = newValue;
            });
         }
}
```

This will one way bind my directive's scope's `selectedItem` property to the value set in the attribute as such

```
<div test selectedItem="thePropertyOnTheController"></div>
```

But what if I want to two way bind? Is there an easy way to set this up without `$watch`'ing the directive's scope's `selectedItem` property and `$parse`'ing the `attr.selectedItem` expression and calling assign witht he parsed expression on `scope.$parent?`

Comment: Use `scope: { selectedItem: "=" }` - it's all in the isolate scope [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.thePropertyOnTheController` might have some value like "Hello"

HTML

```
   <div ng-repeat="photosets in userPhotoSetList">
     <photosets photosetsarray="photosets.photosetDetail">
  </div>
```

script :

```
.directive('photosets', function () {
  return {
      scope: {
               photosetslist : "=photosetsarray"
             },
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
       console.log(scope.photosetslist);
       //"Hello" is output
     }
}
```

If you see `photosetsarray="photosets.photosetDetail""` **photosetsarray** and

```
            scope: {
               photosetslist : "=photosetsarray" **//this name is same as assignee attr**
             },
```

*leftside variable name in html must =  right side variable name in directive*

Comment: What if I want to do this programmatically in code? Any easy way?

Comment: leftside variable name in html must = right side variable name in directive

Comment: Here's the reason I ask - this doesn't work: scope: { options: {imageIndex: '=popupImagesIndex'} }....so my idea is to accomplish the binding in the link function.

Comment: `imageIndex : '=popupImagesIndex'` and `photosetslist : "=photosetsarray"`
the left side assign `photosetsarray` must equal to right side variable of directive scope.

scope: {
               photosetslist : "=photosetsarray" **//this name is same as assignee attr**
             },

AND also I suggest you to take variable as `imageindex` not like `imageIndex`

Please check Edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with variable naming in these situations. Binding to an attribute that is declared as camel case in the directive cannot be accessed as such from the DOM.

```
.directive('test', function () {
  return {
      scope: {
               item : "=selectedItem"
             },
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
         //do some stuff
     }
}
```

So to correctly bind this attribute to a variable on the controller:

```
<div test selected-item="thePropertyOnTheController"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying